# Need more information for the "br_lgv_stat" cookie

Tags: cookies

What is the br_lgv_stat cookie, what is generating it?
It seems to be a cookie for remembering to use either list or grid formatting but I cant find any more information. I dont know its origin, I cant find any reference to what is requesting it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering the same thing, but your idea of what it might do makes perfect sense. I use Woocommerce on a wordpress site and I wanted the 'products' in a list view, instead of a grid with tiles. The option remains a choice for users, and hence, the cookie is there.
The particular plugin is called "Grid/List View for WooCommerce", by the way.